# parsing json input in hadoop java

Tags: java, hadoop

My input data is in hdfs. I am simply trying to do wordcount but there is slight difference.
The data is in json format.
So each line of data is:

```
{"author":"foo", "text": "hello"}
{"author":"foo123", "text": "hello world"}
{"author":"foo234", "text": "hello this world"}
```

I only want to do wordcount of words in "text" part.

How do I do this?

I tried the following variant so far:

```
public static class TokenCounterMapper
    extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(TokenCounterMapper.class);
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        try {

            JSONObject jsn = new JSONObject(value.toString());

            //StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
            String text = (String) jsn.get("text");
            log.info("Logging data");
            log.info(text);
            StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(text);
            while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
                word.set(itr.nextToken());
                context.write(word, one);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:820)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:865)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext.getMapperClass(JobContext.java:199)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:719)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

Comment: He posted code now AND no duplicate, so dont downvote everything like a five-year-old. ;)

Comment: Pig would be a better choice to do that, IMHO. And I don't know why some people take immense pleasure in downvoting. And if you really want to do that, please be kind enough to provide some sensible reason. This is the reason people are moving to other places like Quora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you forgot to embed the JSon library in your Hadoop job jar.
You can have a look there to see how you can build your job with the library:
http://tikalk.com/build-your-first-hadoop-project-maven

Comment: Possibly. But I am using eclipse as an env.. I am able to create jar file successfully on my local machine but then I am sshing this jar to my cluster??

Comment: The code you run in Eclispe may work because of your classpath configuration, but you still need to embed your libraries in the final Job deployed on your Hadoop cluster or at runtime the class won't be found (because they do not exist literally).

Comment: THanks for the insight.. I added this -D mapred.child.env="LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/examples/wordcount/json-20090211.jar" But still the same error :(

Comment: When I was doing some Hadoop jobs, the easier way I found to make it work (if your libraries are not too big) is to embed them directly within the JAR as explained in the articled I provided earlier.

If the libraries are too big for that, depending on your Hadoop architecture there is usualy a Cache system which allow you to load libraries there, but I have never used that yet.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to use external jars with your map reduce code:

1. Include the referenced JAR in the lib subdirectory of the submittable JAR: The job will unpack the JAR from this lib subdirectory into the jobcache on the respective TaskTracker nodes and point your tasks to this directory to make the JAR available to your code. If the JARs are small, change often, and are job-specific this is the preferred method. This is what [@clement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16825894/1150329) suggested in his answer.
2. Install the JAR on the cluster nodes. The easiest way is to place the JAR into `$HADOOP_HOME/lib` directory as everything from this directory is included when a Hadoop daemon starts. Note that a start stop will be needed to make this effective.
3. TaskTrackers will be using the external JAR, so you can provide it by modifying `HADOOP_TASKTRACKER_OPTS` option in the `hadoop-env.sh` configuration file and make it point to the jar. The jar needs to be present at the same path on all the nodes where task-tracker runs.
4. Include the JAR in the “`-libjars`” command line option of the `hadoop jar …` command. The jar will be placed in distributed cache and will be made available to all of the job’s task attempts. Your map-reduce code must use `GenericOptionsParser`. For more details read [this blog post](http://grepalex.com/2013/02/25/hadoop-libjars/).

Comparison:

- ## 1 is a legacy method but discouraged because it has a large negative performance cost.
- ## 2 and #3 are good for private clusters but pretty lame practice as you cannot expect end users to do that.
- ## 4 is the most recommended option.

Read the [main post](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/) from Cloudera).