# parsing twitter json using mapreduce: Java, Pig

Tags: java, json, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I'm sure you might find this question somewhat 'duplicate' but I'm sure I've done my research before posting the same. I also apologize for posting Java & Pig issues in one single thread here but just don't want to create another thread for same problem.

I got a json file with some twitter extracts. I'm trying to perform the parse using java MR & Pig as well, but facing issues. Below is my Java code that I tried writing:

```
public class twitterDataStore {
    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    public static abstract class Map extends MapReduceBase implements 
    Mapper<Object, Text, IntWritable, Reporter>{

        private static final IntWritable one = new IntWritable();
        private Text word = new Text();

        public void map(Object key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> context, Reporter arg3)
        throws IOException{
            try{
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(value.toString());

                String text = (String) jsonObj.get("retweet_count");
                StringTokenizer strToken = new StringTokenizer(text);

                while(strToken.hasMoreTokens()){
                    word.set(strToken.nextToken());
                    context.collect(word, one);
                }
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }
    public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Object, Text, IntWritable, Reporter>{

        @Override
        public void reduce(Object key, Iterator<Text> value,
                OutputCollector<IntWritable, Reporter> context, Reporter arg3)
                throws IOException {
                    while(value.hasNext()){
                        System.out.println(value);
                        if(value.equals("retweet_count"))
                        {
                            System.out.println(value.equals("id_str"));
                        }

                    }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        JobConf conf = new JobConf(twitterDataStore.class);
        conf.setJobName("twitterDataStore");

        conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);

        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf,new Path(args[1]));

        JobClient.runJob(conf);
    }

}
```

The issue is, and you might have gotten it by now, is that I can't do the parsing when I execute the jar, most probably because the json jar isn't included in the package. I tried going with the information provided here: "[parsing json input in hadoop java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825821/parsing-json-input-in-hadoop-java)". But I can't get pass any option. Whatever @Tejas Patil has suggested and @Fraz tried, I couldn't get anything working for my problem. I'll paste the warning generated here also for an FYI:

```
14/04/14 21:09:22 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
```

Coming to Pig(version 0.11) loading, I wrote a JsonLoader load to load my tweet data :

```
data = LOAD '/tmp/twitter.txt' using JsonLoader('in_reply_to_screen_name:chararray,text:chararray,id_str:long,place:chararray,in_reply_to_status_id:chararray, contributors:chararray,retweet_count:CHARARRAY,favorited:chararray,truncated:chararray,source:chararray,in_reply_to_status_id_str:chararray,created_at:chararray, in_reply_to_user_id_str:chararray,in_reply_to_user_id:chararray,user:{(lang:chararray,profile_background_image_url:chararray,id_str:long,default_profile_image: chararray,statuses_count:chararray,profile_link_color:chararray,favourites_count:chararray,profile_image_url_https:chararray,following:chararray, profile_background_color:chararray,description:chararray,notifications:chararray,profile_background_tile:chararray,time_zone:chararray, profile_sidebar_fill_color:chararray,listed_count:chararray,contributors_enabled:chararray,geo_enabled:chararray,created_at:chararray,screen_name:chararray, follow_request_sent:chararray,profile_sidebar_border_color:chararray,protected:chararray,url:chararray,default_profile:chararray,name:chararray, is_translator:chararray,show_all_inline_media:chararray,verified:chararray,profile_use_background_image:chararray,followers_count:chararray,profile_image_url:chararray, id:long,profile_background_image_url_https:chararray,utc_offset:chararray,friends_count:chararray,profile_text_color:chararray,location:chararray)},retweeted:chararray, id:long,coordinates:chararray,geo:chararray');
```

Sorry for pasting everything unnecessarily here but just don't want to miss anything in the explanation.

I was facing issues with declaring some of the fields as 'integer' but when I converted all integers to chararray, the command passed the check. The error I'm getting here is

```
2014-04-14 21:19:24,977 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient - Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
2014-04-14 21:19:24,982 [JobControl] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient - No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
```

The same issue with parsing. I tried registering the json jar before this load, but still the same problem. Can anyone help me out in resolving the issue?

Thanks in advance.
-Adil

Answer (score 0):

You are using TextInputFormat so when you do value.toString(), you get a single line as an input. Not the whole JSON object.

I recommend you use this:

https://github.com/alexholmes/json-mapreduce#an-inputformat-to-work-with-splittable-multi-line-json